# Why does hover text not work with ggplotly, geom_histogram and facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, ggplotly, facet-grid

When using `facet_grid()` in both rows and columns, with a histogram in ggplotly, the x-axis values turn up as NA in the hover text. This doesn't happen if the faceting is only over rows, only over columns, or if the geom is different e.g. `geom_point()`. Am I doing something wrong?

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data(iris)


ggplotly(
  ggplot(data = iris,
         aes(x = Petal.Length))+
    geom_histogram()+
    facet_grid(Species~round(Sepal.Length))
)
```

[image: Facet grid histogram with ggplotly]

Comment: works for me -- using the dev version installed from `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`

Comment: I have the dev version installed myself, and it doesn't work. The error is replicated on my colleague's computer who doesn't have the dev version installed.

Comment: mac or windows or linux? I don't have any insight on this one... maybe if you include `sessionInfo()` above someone will get an idea.

Comment: Hey @GordonMcDonald: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot 3.2.1` and `plotly 4.9.0`, I was able to get this working with a simple workaround—in the `ggplotly` call, pass the `x` aesthetic to the `tooltip` parameter; like so:

`ggplotly(ggplot_histogram, tooltip = c("x", "count"))`

(You also have to pass the `count` aesthetic; otherwise, kinda defeats the point of a histogram).